# Copy an Excel Sheet to another Workbook in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel sheet which contains a Signature Line. I tried to copy this sheet to another workbook, but the values of the sheet can be copied, except the signature line. I think this copy method is based on cells.

How to get signature line to another workbook. Here is my code

```
        Excel._Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlTemplateWB;
        Excel.Workbook xlTempWB;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;

        //Open Bench Sheet Template
        xlTemplateWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\TempProjects\test.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", 
        "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        //Save As a temporary workbook
        xlTemplateWB.SaveAs(@"C:\\TempProjects\mytmp.xlsx");

        //Open temporary workbook
        xlTempWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\TempProjects\my.xlsx", 0, false, 5, true, "",
        true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        xlTemplateWB.Worksheets.Copy(xlTempWB.Worksheets["Sheet1"]);
        xlTemplateWB.Close(true, missing, missing);
        releaseObject(xlTemplateWB);

        xlTempWB.Save();

        //Close Workbooks
        xlTempWB.Close(true, missing, missing);
        xlApp.Quit();

        //Release Objects
        releaseObject(xlTempWB);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: I think this is on purpose: "if anyone [...] alters the document, the application removes the digital signature, serving as an indicator to all that someone may have altered the document": http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/586-tips-inserting-signature-lines-into-excel-and-word

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already can add signature to the excel/world document but in excel file, this signature window cannot be close. I have to send keys which is not a good method. In Word, I used Quick parts and it solved my problem. Actually now i tried for excel and it seems work. If all my tests will be successfull, I will add the answer.